# How to broadcast Video using UDPCLient Class in C# over internet?

Tags: c#-4.0, udp, video-streaming, voip, udpclient

I am trying to develop a Video Client/functionality that captures video using webcam and transfers to other **servent** (server-client) somewhere on the internet. I am using UDPCLient Class to do that.

I want my application to be able to listen and tarnsmit video captured from webcam. The capturing, transmission and receiving works fine when i do that on local network.

But when i test the application from behind router (across two differnt networks/internet) after forwarding respective ports, the internet connectivity is lost on both routers (They hang up or something) and i need to restart the routers or switch to an alternate connection. The configuration is as follows:

Servent 1 <--> Router1 <--> Internet Connection#01

Servent 02 <---> Router2 <---> Internet Connection#02

Both connections are on separate DSL Line. One of the routers is ZTE brand and the other is of Netgear.

Code for listenning/transmission is as follows:

```
private void StartSockets()
    {
        //For testing across internet i use IPAddress obtained via different function
        var IPAddress = getMyIpAddress();
        this.udpSender = new UdpClient(IpAddress, 4000);
        this.udpListener = new UdpClient(4000);
    }
private IPAddress getMyIpAddress()
        {
            IPAddress localIP ;//= AddressAr[0];
            localIP = IPAddress.Parse(GetPublicIP());
            return localIP;
        }
public string GetPublicIP()
        {
            String direction = "";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            //Search for the ip in the html
            int first = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
            int last = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
            direction = direction.Substring(first, last - first);

            return direction;
        }
```

Code for receiving response is as follows:

```
private void ReceiveData()
        {
            //For testing across internet i use IPAddress obtained via different function
            var IPAddress = getMyIpAddress();

            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress, myPort);
         try
                {
                    byte[] receiveBytes = this.udpListener.Receive(ref ep);
                    this.OnReadImage(new ImageEventArgs(this.ByteToImage(receiveBytes)));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

        }
```

If i test on local network , i use DNSHostname to get ip address (private ip addresses) and video works fine on local network. That does not work over internet so i switch to live Ip Address and thus i use the method of getPublicIpAddress().

1. I know there is something seriously wrong with my approach? What would be right approach?
2. Should i switch to TCP Listenner? I intend to have multiple receiver of same video in future. So would that affect?
3. Can UDP clients cause routers to crash, hang up and restart? How can i avoid that?
4. Lastly, if were to avoid port-forwarding what would be the best strategy?

Please help.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Guys if anything is unclear, i can add more description to the question. Looks like nobody had this problem before? (wondering)